# SelectedDate event is not trigger when the current date selected in Nullable date picker Custom Control in xamarin.Fomrs

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have implemented the nullable date picker to show the placeholder to date field as well as the null date in it, You can see the code below

Now the issue here is when I click on the current date then the DateSelected event is not getting trigger, it triggers when you select the previous date or next dates but not getting selected for the current date.

Thanks in advance.

NDateControl.cs

```
public class NDatePicker : DatePicker
{
    public NDatePicker()
    {
        Format = "MM'/'dd'/'yyyy";
    }
    public string _originalFormat = null;

    public static readonly BindableProperty PlaceHolderProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(PlaceHolder), typeof(string), typeof(c), "'MM/DD/YYYY'");
    public string PlaceHolder
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(PlaceHolderProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PlaceHolderProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty NullableDateProperty =
    BindableProperty.Create(nameof(NullableDate), typeof(DateTime?), typeof(NDatePicker), null, defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay);
    public DateTime? NullableDate
    {
        get { return (DateTime?)GetValue(NullableDateProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(NullableDateProperty, value);
            UpdateDate();
        }
    }

    private void UpdateDate()
    {
        if (NullableDate != null)
        {
            if (_originalFormat != null)
            {
                Format = _originalFormat;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Format = PlaceHolder;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
    {
        base.OnBindingContextChanged();
        if (BindingContext != null)
        {
            _originalFormat = Format;
            UpdateDate();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);

        if (propertyName == DateProperty.PropertyName || (propertyName == IsFocusedProperty.PropertyName
            && !IsFocused && (Date.ToString(Constant.DATE_FORMAT) == DateTime.Now.ToString(Constant.DATE_FORMAT))))
        {
            AssignValue();
        }

        if (propertyName == NullableDateProperty.PropertyName && NullableDate.HasValue)
        {
            Date = NullableDate.Value;
            if (Date.ToString(_originalFormat) == DateTime.Now.ToString(_originalFormat))
            {
                //this code was done because when date selected is the actual date the"DateProperty" does not raise  
                UpdateDate();
            }
        }
    }
    
    public void AssignValue()
    {
        NullableDate = Date;
        UpdateDate();
    }
}
```

NDatePickerDroid.cs

```
public class NDatePickerDroid : ViewRenderer<NDatePicker, EditText>
{
    DatePickerDialog _dialog;
    public NDatePickerDroid(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<NDatePicker> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        SetNativeControl(new EditText(Context));
        if (Control == null || e.NewElement == null)
            return;

        Control.TextSize = 14;
        Control.Click += OnPickerClick;
        Control.Text = Element.Date.ToString(Element.Format);
        Control.KeyListener = null;
        Control.FocusChange += OnPickerFocusChange;
        Control.Enabled = Element.IsEnabled;
    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

        if (e.PropertyName == Xamarin.Forms.DatePicker.DateProperty.PropertyName || e.PropertyName == Xamarin.Forms.DatePicker.FormatProperty.PropertyName)
            SetDate(Element.Date);
    }

    void OnPickerFocusChange(object sender, Android.Views.View.FocusChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.HasFocus)
        {
            ShowDatePicker();
        }
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (Control != null)
        {
            Control.Click -= OnPickerClick;
            Control.FocusChange -= OnPickerFocusChange;

            if (_dialog != null)
            {
                _dialog.Hide();
                _dialog.Dispose();
                _dialog = null;
            }
        }

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    void OnPickerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ShowDatePicker();
    }

    void SetDate(DateTime date)
    {
        Control.Text = date.ToString(Element.Format);
        Element.Date = date;
    }

    private void ShowDatePicker()
    {
        CreateDatePickerDialog(Element.Date.Year, Element.Date.Month - 1, Element.Date.Day);
        _dialog.Show();
    }

    void CreateDatePickerDialog(int year, int month, int day)
    {
        NDatePicker view = Element;
        _dialog = new DatePickerDialog(Context, (o, e) =>
        {
            view.Date = e.Date;
            ((IElementController)view).SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedProperty, false);
            Control.ClearFocus();

            _dialog = null;
        }, year, month, day);

        _dialog.SetButton(Constant.DONE, (sender, e) =>
        {
            SetDate(_dialog.DatePicker.DateTime);
            Element.Format = Element._originalFormat;
            Element.AssignValue();
        });
    }
}
```

NDatePickeriOS.cs

```
public class NDatePickeriOS : DatePickerRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<DatePicker> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (e.NewElement != null && Control != null)
        {
            AddClearButton();

            Control.Font = Control.Font.WithSize(14);
            Control.BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.Line;
            Control.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.LightGray.CGColor;
            Control.Layer.BorderWidth = 1;

            if (Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Tablet)
            {
                Control.Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(25);
            }
        }
    }

    private void AddClearButton()
    {
        UIToolbar originalToolbar = Control.InputAccessoryView as UIToolbar;

        if (originalToolbar != null && originalToolbar.Items.Length <= 2)
        {
            var clearButton = new UIBarButtonItem(Constant.CLEAR, UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, ((sender, ev) =>
            {
                NDatePicker baseDatePicker = Element as NDatePicker;
                Element.Unfocus();
                Element.Date = DateTime.Now;
                //baseDatePicker.CleanDate();
            }));

            var newItems = new List<UIBarButtonItem>();
            foreach (var item in originalToolbar.Items)
            {
                newItems.Add(item);
            }

            newItems.Insert(0, clearButton);

            originalToolbar.Items = newItems.ToArray();
            originalToolbar.SetNeedsDisplay();
        }
    }
}
```

The XAML is

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="0,2" HeightRequest="60">
        <control:NDatePicker NullableDate="{Binding DateAnswer}" DateSelected="DateChanged" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: Could you show your xaml codes ?

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT updated the question, please check

Comment: The DatePick's default Date is DateTime.Today.So I think if you select the  current date,it will not trige the datechange event.

Comment: Yes, I understand this that’s why the date change event is not triggered

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT Is there any other way to trigger this event on the date selected(OK button)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center) to send a message to your page when you select the current date.

```
 _dialog.SetButton(Constant.DONE, (sender, e) =>
    {
        SetDate(_dialog.DatePicker.DateTime);
        Element.Format = Element._originalFormat;
        Element.AssignValue();
        if (_dialog.DatePicker.DateTime == DateTime.Today)
          {
            MessagingCenter.Send<Object,DateTime>(this, "SameDate", view.Date);
          }
    });
```

in your page.xaml.cs:

```
 public YourPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Object,DateTime>(this, "SameDate", (sender,args) => 
         {
            DateTime dateTime = args; //triggered here
         });
    }
```

Comment: I will check this and let you know, Thanks in advance